# Error with MySQLi INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli

I have ths query, again i'm trying to pass from pop3 account to mysql database:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO procesa_emails (body_mail, uid_message, fecha, from, to, subject, message_id) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities(str_replace("'","",str_replace('"','',$message))))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($uid_mess))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($fecha))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($from))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($to))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($subject))."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($mui))."')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

But It returns me:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, subject, message_id)
```

I tried with str_replace("'","",str_replace('"'.'')) But It also doesn't work

Comment: May be a silly question, but did you maybe mispell `procesa_emails`? Maybe `process_emails`?

Comment: procesa_emails is the database name

Comment: ok, just thought I'd ask. The `s` and `a` are next to each other on the keyword, one never knows.

Comment: From and to may be reserved keywords in mysql. Add backticks around your field names, that'll eliminate that. For e.g: `from`, `to` - its always considered good practice to do that anyway. Good habit to get into!

Comment: Ok, yes, well, i speak spanish, emmm and process in spanish is procesa or procesar xD

Comment: @Darkness Si, no problema amigo ;-)

Comment: @LokiSinclair i tried: INSERT INTO procesa_emails (body_mail,uid_message,fecha,from,to,subject,message_id) but it also returns: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,to,subject,message_id) VALUES ('ESTIMADO GUILLERMO\r\n\r\nBUENA TARDE\r\n\r' at line 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). So, if you want to use that inside your query, you need to wrap it in backticks, like so:

```
mysqli_query($con,"
INSERT INTO procesa_emails (body_mail, uid_message, fecha, `from`, ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: aahh good catch! Was just about to look up the reserved words list.